# axios post 403 forbidden but postman works

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, post, axios

use axios post get 403 forbidden but postman and axios get all works

Server: Spring Boot localhost:8080

Web: Vue.js + Axios localhost:80

Spring Boot CORS CONFIG:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(1800)
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:80/");
    }
}
```

Vue.js ProxyTable:

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api':{
    target: "http://localhost:8080/",
    changeOrigin:true,
  }},
```

Axios func:

```
  doLogin(){
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/te',
      data: {
        userNumber: 'hi'
      }
    });
```

Spring Boot Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/te")
public String Test(@RequestBody HashMap<String,String> map) {
    return map.get("userNumber");
}
```

then,in MSEdge localhost:80/ :

[403 forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT7R1.png)

however in postman it works well:

[postman works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXPu.png)

I've tried for 3 hours ,and now I'm very tired...

Comment: CORS usually doesn't return 403, when its a CORS issue it usually is so that the server will return the correct response, but the browser will stop you from viewing the response because of missing CORS-headers... i might be wrong, but are you sure its a CORS issue?

Comment: in fact,i dont know what happened....i tried 'get' with a new controller without args, it works well,just can't post...(posting without payload also got 403)

Comment: what i can see from your webbrowser (i can't read Chinese) is that it looks like the request from axios is made to `127.0.0.1:80` so is the proxy working?

Comment: yes it works,i tried to use post man get 127.0.0.1:80/api/te ,it works...and 127.0.0.1:8080/api/te in the same way.now i solved it ,look my answer,even if i dont know why ;P

Comment: I think i've found out why,look my answer.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I HAVE SOLVED IT NOW!!!!

that's because I've configured CORS

`allowedOrigins("http://localhost:80/");`

and

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api':{
    target: "http://localhost:8080/",
    changeOrigin:true,
  }},
```

Reason:

1. allowedOrigin should be `http://localhost:80` , adding '`/`' in the end is a mistake.
2. `proxyTable.'/api'.changeOrigin:true` will just set Host Header to target,NOT set Origin Header to target,this is DIFFERENT from allowedOringins method in SpringBoot CORS CONFIG,your request's origin is still htpp://localhost (the page that request)。

so the right code is:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(1800)
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost");
    }
}
```

and

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api':{
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    changeOrigin:true,
  }},
```

;P