# Axios GET request resulting in 403. Postman works

Tags: web-scraping, axios, cors, postman

I am trying get a page's HTML (on someone else's site) with an Axios GET request from my node server. But the request is returning a 403 error. The same request works on Postman.

```js
 axios(
      'https://www.ssense.com/en-ca/women/product/laura-lombardi/gold-cable-chain-necklace/6378111',
      {
        headers: { // tried to fake the user-agent but this didn't change anything
          'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36',
        },
      }
    )
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Some have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881437/axios-post-403-forbidden-but-postman-works) that this is a CORS issue. This confuses me. I thought cors was something that only effects browsers. If it is a CORS issue, why would it effect axios? Since I have no control over the site's server, I of course can't change their cors settings. So what is the solution?

Why can't I get the response in axios like I can in Postman? Is there some a way to get the HTML in node like postman does?

Answer (score 0):

Postman, as a developer tool and in contrast as browsers, does not enforce CORS. That is the reason why it works on Postman and why it does not work on a browser.
I am not entirely sure about your context, but sometimes, the solution when we can not control the server or API we are requesting and getting CORS issues is using a proxy. Like [this one](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere), for example.

Comment: I'm not using a browser though, I'm using axios on the backend. So why does axios enforce cors on my backend?

Comment: Unless it is on a developer tool, like Postman or browser extensions, CORS will be mandatory, either on the back-end or front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to send exact headers whatever server sends to the browser. I can solve this issue using scrapy . Thanks –

Comment: exact headers? what headers? the headers that the site I'm trying to scrape sends to the browser?

Comment: Go to network tap from devtools then go to xhr tab  and you will see many requests are sent by the server and among them you have to find out the exact url and click( in name column)  and click the header and you will seen response headers, and request headers . You need only Request headers fields. Thanks

Comment: ahh so like copy the request a browser would send?

Answer (score -1):

Adding `mode: 'no-cors'` to the headers made it intermittently work but I don't even know if that's a real header so I think it was just a coincidence (I think it's an axios option not a header). I then realized that *Postman* was also giving me 403.

Upon closer look the html:
**"Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website"**

Says it can happen because:

- javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
- Your browser does not support cookies

Switching to puppeteer since puppeteer can load javascript, not sure axios can. But still had the issue.
Going to look into this stackoverflow question
[How to avoid being detected as bot on Puppeteer and Phantomjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs)